# stopping a long poll with rxjava in android

Tags: java, android, rx-java, retrofit2

I am doing a `long poll` to an API from an android client using retrofit and rxjava. In this case, we wait for a **200** or **408** timeout response from an API and handle the response or reconnect to wait again for more data. This works just fine. I need to stop rx from retrying on certain error codes *(like a 500)* or if I want to interrupt the process, for example my app was background so let's stop the long poll.

```
 retrofitInterface.startPolling()  //returns an Observable 
                    .repeat()
                    .retry()
                    .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Stuff>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(List<Stuff> updates) {
                             //process stuff
                            }

                        }
                    });
```

I'm not sure if `repeatWhen` and `retryWhen` is the right solution here, where I want to keep repeating and retrying http calls to the API but stop repeating in some condition *(say I flip a bool in the class to false)* or stop retrying if the status code is a **500** instead of say a **408**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier if you wrap your request answer in object of type `<Response<?>>`, this gives you control over the error code.

What I did for that use case is throwing a specific exception when I have some specific error code:

```
public <T> T throwExceptionIfFailure(T res) {
    Response result = (Response<?>) res;
    if (!result.isSuccessful()) {
        try {
            String msg = result.errorBody().string();
            if (result.code() == 401 || result.code() == 403) {
                invalidateToken();
                msg = context.getString(R.string.invalid_credential);
            } else if (result.code() == 502) {
                msg = context.getString(R.string.server_down);
            }

            throw Exceptions.propagate(new IOException(msg));
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw Exceptions.propagate(e);
        }
    } else {
        return res;
    }
}
```

and I added this method in a map function of RX:

```
    serviceRetrofit.getContacts()
            .map(result -> serviceRetrofit.throwExceptionIfFailure(result))
            .map(result -> createOrUpdateContact(result))
            .retry(4)
            .onErrorReturn(error -> handleErrorEvent(error))
            .doOnCompleted(() -> emitStoreChange(new Store.StoreChangeEvent()))
            .subscribe();
```